# How to make Voting api not cache

Tags: 7, rating

For my application with several different voters, I want the caching table (votingapi_cache) to never be populated. Is there a hook or a configuration I can implement so that no caching happens at all?

Answer (score 0):

The function [`votingapi_add_results()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/votingapi/tree/votingapi.module?id=4ec7ba8bbd64611be1f8e9f395b68adae813d40d#n287) is responsible for writing records to the `votingapi_cache` table. Immediately afterwards, it [invokes](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/votingapi/tree/votingapi.module?h=7.x-2.12#n455) `hook_votingapi_results()` which any module can use to wipe out the table.

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_votingapi_results().
 */
function MYMODULE_votingapi_results() {
  db_truncate('votingapi_cache')->execute();
}
```